# Disable Flex keyboardEvent

Tags: apache-flex, flex-builder-3

How to disable alt+tab, window+d keyboard shortcuts in Flex Air Application?

So that our application sticks on and user can not open any other application, when our Air application is running.

Comment: You can't from within the AIR app, since these are system key-combos. Only possible solution is to go through a native extension.

Comment: The keyboard events are triggered by the OS and sent to the active app. You cannot bypass them !

Answer (score 0):

If you control the pc itself, there seems to be a way:

- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html
- http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/95652-disabling-alt-tab-other-keys.html#post828847